# User defined function to produce unique values of selected variables

Tags: r, dplyr, user-defined-functions, tidyverse

I've written a simple user function to produce the unique values of a given column like this:

```
 > get.values <- function(df, colNamestr) {
      df %>%
      select(colNamestr) %>%
      distinct()
 }
```

sample data as follows:

```
myData <- data.frame(
    variable1 = c("cat", "cat", "dog"), 
    variable2 = c("yes", "no", "maybe"),
    variable3 = c("yellow", "yellow", "white")
)
```

When I run the function as follows:

```
get.values(myData, 'variable1') ... result is:
  variable1
1       cat
2       dog
```

I want to expand this function so that I can call on multiple column names (about 15) at once (my actual data has 2000 columns), and output a data frame with all the unique values of the variables such as this.

```
get.values(myData, c('variable1', 'variable2', 'variable3')
     variable1  variable2 variable3
    1       cat  yes      yellow
    2       dog  no       white
    3            maybe
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3):

Here, we can use `map`

```
library(purrr)
map(names(myData), get.values, df = myData) %>%
      reduce(rowr::cbind.fill, fill = "")
#    variable1 variable2 variable3
#1       cat       yes    yellow
#2       dog        no     white
#3               maybe
```

Comment: This is really neat. Is there a way of calling on only selected variables? I have 2000 columns and I don't want to run the get.values function on all of them.

Comment: @NewBee You can just replace `names(myData)` with the `names(myData)[c(1, 3)]` for selected columns

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `select_at` functions

```r
library(tidyverse)
myData <- data.frame(variable1=c("cat", "cat", "dog"), variable2=c("yes", "no", "maybe"), variable3=c("yellow", "yellow", "white"))


get.values <- function(df, colNamestr) {
  df %>%
    select_at(colNamestr) %>%
    distinct()
}

myData %>% 
get.values(vars(everything()))
#>   variable1 variable2 variable3
#> 1       cat       yes    yellow
#> 2       cat        no    yellow
#> 3       dog     maybe     white
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

It is nice that now your function operates with select helpers, just surround the variables that you want with `vars()`

Comment: This is really cool, but I want the unique values of each variable. This approach results in the repetition of values for variable1 and variable3 and only gives me the unique values of variable2....

Answer (score 1):

We can `select` the `colNamestr` columns, use `unique` to get unique values from each of those columns, append `NA`s to columns with shorter length and bind them together.

```
library(tidyverse)

get.values <- function(df, colNamestr) {
  map(myData %>% select(colNamestr), unique) %>% map_dfc(`[`, 1:max(lengths(.)))  
}

get.values(myData, 'variable1')
#  variable1
#  <fct>    
#1 cat      
#2 dog      

get.values(myData, c('variable1', 'variable2'))

# variable1 variable2
#  <fct>     <fct>    
#1 cat       yes      
#2 dog       no       
#3 NA        maybe
```

If there are multiple columns that you want to apply this to you can use non-standard evaluation

```
get.values <- function(df, colNamestr) {
  map(myData %>% select({{colNamestr}}), unique) %>% map_dfc(`[`, 1:max(lengths(.)))  
}
```

and pass range of columns

```
get.values(myData, variable1:variable3)

#  variable1 variable2 variable3
#  <fct>     <fct>     <fct>    
#1 cat       yes       yellow   
#2 dog       no        white    
#3 NA        maybe     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping things within the **tidyverse**, we can rewrite your function to take advantage of quasiquotation:

```
get.values <- function(df, ...) {

  cols <- enquos(...)

  df %>% 
    select(!!!cols) %>% 
    distinct() %>% 
    mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
    mutate_all(~ifelse(duplicated(.), ' ', .)) %>% 
    mutate_all(~rev(sort(.)))
}
```

Here, `get.values` expects to be given a data frame, followed by any number of column names (quoted or unquoted). Using `enquos` allows us to take advantage of all of the tidyverse's selection grammar:

```
myData <- data.frame(variable1=c("cat", "cat", "dog"), variable2=c("yes", "no", "maybe"), variable3=c("yellow", "yellow", "white"))

get.values(myData, variable1)

  variable1
1       dog
2       cat

get.values(myData, variable1, variable2)

  variable1 variable2
1       dog       yes
2       cat        no
3               maybe

# Using strings works just fine:
get.values(myData, c('variable1', 'variable2'))

  variable1 variable2
1       dog       yes
2       cat        no
3               maybe

get.values(myData, variable1:variable3)

  variable1 variable2 variable3
1       dog       yes    yellow
2       cat        no     white
3               maybe          

get.values(myData, ends_with('2'))

  variable2
1       yes
2        no
3     maybe
```